# Dynamic Form validation in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, yii

I can't seem to get javascript form validation working in yii

I want to point the script towards the user form and include it in the clientOptions but it's saying validateform is not defined.

I tried to get the default functionality working but there doesn't seem to be anyway to validate dynamically created fields in Yii without creating your own function like this. I will know the fields for this particular instance so I can put them in manually for now

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('booster.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnChange' => false,
        'validateOnType' => false,
        'validateOnSubmit' => 'js:validateForm',
    ),
        ));
?>
     <?php
$varform = new DynamicForm();
$varform->attributes = $user->getDynamicFormConfig();
$varform->model_name = 'user';
echo $varform->run();
?>
```

JS

```
function validateForm()
    {
    var a=document.forms["#user-form"]["user_TestQuestion"].value;
    var b=document.forms["#user-form"]["user_NEWQUESTION"].value;

    if (a==null || a=="",b==null || b=="")
      {
      alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
      return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`validateOnSubmit` is boolean parameter. If you want to do something with your fields on validation you may use:

1. `beforeValidate` function, the function that will be invoked before performing ajax-based validation triggered by form submission action **(available only when validateOnSubmit is set true)**. The expected function signature should be `beforeValidate(form) {...}`, where 'form' is the jquery representation of the form object. If the return value of this function is NOT true, the validation will be cancelled.
2. `afterValidate` function, the function that will be invoked after performing ajax-based validation triggered by form submission action **(available only when validateOnSubmit is set true)**. The expected function signature should be `afterValidate(form, data, hasError) {...}`, where 'form' is the jquery representation of the form object; 'data' is the JSON response from the server-side validation; 'hasError' is a boolean value indicating whether there is any validation error. If the return value of this function is NOT true, the normal form submission will be cancelled.